# Numbers issue in for loops

Tags: java, arrays, math

I'm making a program that reads fences using terrain representation. Right now the code looks at the array and reports back how much fencing is needed, with each side of a 1 being 2.5m. The problem with it is that I can't figure out what's wrong with the numbers. It displays the corner values fine, but the side values are incorrect, except for the last column which displays the right values, but that might just be a coincidence. I have i's and j's to represent x and y values, here is all of my code so far.

```
package assignment_2;

public class Fencing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean b = true;
        double corner = 0;
        double core = 0;
        double side = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int[][] map = { 
            { 0, 1, 1, 0 }, 
            { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, 
            { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, 
            { 1, 1, 0, 1 } 
        };
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if (map[i][j] != 1 && map[i][j] != 0) {
                    b = false;
                    System.out.println("--> A value of " + map[i][j] + " was found at " + i + "," + j);
                }
            }
        }
        if (b == false && i == 4) {
            System.out.println("The map is invalid");
            return;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Map is valid");
        }
        if (map[0][0] == 1) {
            corner += 5;
            if (map[1][0] == 1 && map[0][1] == 1) {
                corner += 0;
            }
            if (map[1][0] != 1 && map[0][1] != 1) {
                corner += 5;
            }
            if (map[1][0] != 1 && map[0][1] == 1 || map[1][0] == 1 && map[0][1] != 1) {
                corner += 2.5;
            }
        } else {
            corner += 0;
        }
        if (map[0][3] == 1) {
            corner += 5;
            if (map[1][3] == 1 && map[0][2] == 1) {
                corner += 0;
            }
            if (map[1][3] != 1 && map[0][2] != 1) {
                corner += 5;
            }
            if (map[1][3] != 1 && map[0][2] == 1 || map[1][3] == 1 && map[0][2] != 1) {
                corner += 2.5;
            }
        } else {
            corner += 0;
        }
        if (map[3][0] == 1) {
            corner += 5;
            if (map[3][1] == 1 && map[2][0] == 1) {
                corner += 0;
            }
            if (map[3][1] != 1 && map[02][0] != 1) {
                corner += 5;
            }
            if (map[3][1] != 1 && map[2][0] == 1 || map[3][1] == 1 && map[2][0] != 1) {
                corner += 2.5;
            }
        } else {
            corner += 0;
        }
        if (map[3][3] == 1) {
            corner += 5;
            if (map[3][2] == 1 && map[2][3] == 1) {
                corner += 0;
            }
            if (map[3][2] != 1 && map[2][3] != 1) {
                corner += 5;
            }
            if (map[3][2] != 1 && map[2][3] == 1 || map[3][2] == 1 && map[2][3] != 1) {
                corner += 2.5;
            }
        } else {
            corner += 0;
        }
        System.out.println("Corner fencing = " + corner);
        for (i = 1; i > 2; i++) { // Top
            if (map[0][j] == 1) {
                side += 2.5;
                if (map[i + 1][0] == 1 && map[i - 1][0] == 1) {
                    side += 0;
                }
                if (map[i + 1][0] != 1 || map[i - 1][0] != 1) {
                    side += 2.5;
                }
                if (map[i + 1][0] != 1 && map[i - 1][0] != 1) {
                    side += 5;
                }
            } else {
                side += 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("After the first row, fencing = " + side);
        for (i = 1; i > 2; i++) { // Bottom
            if (map[i][3] == 1) {
                side += 2.5;
                if (map[i + 1][3] == 1 && map[i - 1][3] == 1) {
                    side += 0;
                }
                if (map[i + 1][3] != 1 || map[i - 1][3] != 1) {
                    side += 2.5;
                }
                if (map[i + 1][3] != 1 && map[i - 1][3] != 1) {
                    side += 5;
                }
            } else {
                side += 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("After the bottom row, fencing = " + side);
        for (j = 1; j < 3; j++) {// Right
            if (map[3][j] == 1) {
                side += 2.5;
                if (map[3][j + 1] == 1 && map[3][j - 1] == 1) {
                    side += 0;
                }
                if (map[3][j + 1] != 1 || map[3][j - 1] != 1) {
                    side += 2.5;
                }
                if (map[3][j + 1] != 1 && map[3][j - 1] != 1) {
                    side += 5;
                }
            } else {
                side += 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("After the first column, fencing = " + side);
        for (j = 1; j < 3; j++) {// Left
            if (map[0][j] == 1) {
                side += 2.5;
                if (map[0][j + 1] == 1 && map[0][j - 1] == 1) {
                    side += 0;
                }
                if (map[0][j + 1] != 1 || map[0][j - 1] != 1) {
                    side += 2.5;
                }
                if (map[0][j + 1] != 1 && map[0][j - 1] != 1) {
                    side += 5;
                }
            } else {
                side += 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("After the last column, fencing = " + side);
    }
}
```

The corners work properly, but the problem is the sides (the for loops). The sides run throught the current line of the array and if the number is a 1, it checks the numbers beside them and adds 2.5m if it is a 0. The issue looks like it's something to do with the i's and j's making the value incorrect but I'm not very sure what's wrong with them. Can anyone help me with this?

Here is the current output:

```
Corner fencing = 12.5

After the first row, fencing = 0.0

After the bottom row, fencing = 0.0

After the first column, fencing = 5.0

After the last column, fencing = 15.0
```

And here is the expected output:

```
Corner fencing = 12.5

After the first row, fencing = 5.0

After the bottom row, fencing = 10.0

After the first column, fencing = 15.0

After the last column, fencing = 20.0
```

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you are trying to do / what you expect. Please be more clear.

Comment: It may be beneficial to you to use the IDE debugging features

Comment: Same, not sure what you're trying to do. Provide current output and expected output.

Comment: `for (i = 1; i > 2; i++) { // Top
            if (map[0][j] == 1) {` these lines! i and j are not properly used.  `1 > 2` ?

Comment: Sorry, what im trying to make the code add 2.5m for the sides of 1's. so for example if this line was the top: 0101 it would add 2.5m for the top part of the first 1 and another 2.5m for the side of the 1, since it is next to a 0. The corners are ignored in the side parts of the code.

Comment: I've added the current and expected outputs to the OP

Comment: Still it not clear what you are trying to do, 1st try to explain what does the following represent:
After the first row, fencing = 0.0
After the bottom row, fencing = 0.0
After the first column, fencing = 5.0
After the last column, fencing = 15.0

What is the equation that the above is based on? 
its probably a mathematical error!

Comment: your code is too lengthy. try to narrow it down

Comment: For every 1 that has something beside it that is not a 1, it adds 2.5 to the side variable. So the current calculations for the sides are saying that the top row adds 0m of fencing when it should add 5m. Same situation for the bottom row. The sides get values, but only the first column is correct, adding 5m of fencing. The last column adds 10m for some reason.

Comment: @MemeBoi I've added the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand what a fence is in your code or what corners/sides represent but I will point out several problems that your code has, and where things might have gone wrong.

**1- Shared local variables:**

`int i,j;` are shared between several blocks so changing those in one block will definitely effect their state in another.

**Sol:**
If the vars are meant to have the same name -> use  named blocks

**2- Wrong conditions:** there are two wrong conditions in your code -bottom and top for loops-

```
(i = 1; i > 2; i++)
```

**Here is the modified code:**

```
public class Fencing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean b = true;
        double corner = 0;
        double core = 0;
        double side = 0;

        int[][] map = { 
            { 0, 1, 1, 0 }, 
            { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, 
            { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, 
            { 1, 1, 0, 1 } 
        };

        firstBlock:{
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if (map[i][j] != 1 && map[i][j] != 0) {
                    b = false;
                    System.out.println("--> A value of " + map[i][j] + " was found at " + i + "," + j);
                }
            }
        }
        if (b == false && i == 4) {
            System.out.println("The map is invalid");
            return;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Map is valid");
        }
        if (map[0][0] == 1) {
            corner += 5;
            if (map[1][0] == 1 && map[0][1] == 1) {
                corner += 0;
            }
            if (map[1][0] != 1 && map[0][1] != 1) {
                corner += 5;
            }
            if (map[1][0] != 1 && map[0][1] == 1 || map[1][0] == 1 && map[0][1] != 1) {
                corner += 2.5;
            }
        } else {
            corner += 0;
        }
        if (map[0][3] == 1) {
            corner += 5;
            if (map[1][3] == 1 && map[0][2] == 1) {
                corner += 0;
            }
            if (map[1][3] != 1 && map[0][2] != 1) {
                corner += 5;
            }
            if (map[1][3] != 1 && map[0][2] == 1 || map[1][3] == 1 && map[0][2] != 1) {
                corner += 2.5;
            }
        } else {
            corner += 0;
        }
        if (map[3][0] == 1) {
            corner += 5;
            if (map[3][1] == 1 && map[2][0] == 1) {
                corner += 0;
            }
            if (map[3][1] != 1 && map[02][0] != 1) {
                corner += 5;
            }
            if (map[3][1] != 1 && map[2][0] == 1 || map[3][1] == 1 && map[2][0] != 1) {
                corner += 2.5;
            }
        } else {
            corner += 0;
        }
        if (map[3][3] == 1) {
            corner += 5;
            if (map[3][2] == 1 && map[2][3] == 1) {
                corner += 0;
            }
            if (map[3][2] != 1 && map[2][3] != 1) {
                corner += 5;
            }
            if (map[3][2] != 1 && map[2][3] == 1 || map[3][2] == 1 && map[2][3] != 1) {
                corner += 2.5;
            }
        } else {
            corner += 0;
        }
        System.out.println("Corner fencing = " + corner);
        }
       secondBlock:{ 
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            for (i = 1; i < 2; i++) { // Top
            if (map[0][j] == 1) {
                side += 2.5;
                if (map[i + 1][0] == 1 && map[i - 1][0] == 1) {
                    side += 0;
                }
                if (map[i + 1][0] != 1 || map[i - 1][0] != 1) {
                    side += 2.5;
                }
                if (map[i + 1][0] != 1 && map[i - 1][0] != 1) {
                    side += 5;
                }
            } else {
                side += 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("After the first row, fencing = " + side);}
        thirdBlock:{
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            for (i = 1; i < 2; i++) { // Bottom
            if (map[i][3] == 1) {
                side += 2.5;
                if (map[i + 1][3] == 1 && map[i - 1][3] == 1) {
                    side += 0;
                }
                if (map[i + 1][3] != 1 || map[i - 1][3] != 1) {
                    side += 2.5;
                }
                if (map[i + 1][3] != 1 && map[i - 1][3] != 1) {
                    side += 5;
                }
            } else {
                side += 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("After the bottom row, fencing = " + side);}
        fourthBlock:{
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
        for (j = 1; j < 3; j++) {// Right
            if (map[3][j] == 1) {
                side += 2.5;
                if (map[3][j + 1] == 1 && map[3][j - 1] == 1) {
                    side += 0;
                }
                if (map[3][j + 1] != 1 || map[3][j - 1] != 1) {
                    side += 2.5;
                }
                if (map[3][j + 1] != 1 && map[3][j - 1] != 1) {
                    side += 5;
                }
            } else {
                side += 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("After the first column, fencing = " + side);}
        lastBlock:{
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
        for (j = 1; j < 3; j++) {// Left
            if (map[0][j] == 1) {
                side += 2.5;
                if (map[0][j + 1] == 1 && map[0][j - 1] == 1) {
                    side += 0;
                }
                if (map[0][j + 1] != 1 || map[0][j - 1] != 1) {
                    side += 2.5;
                }
                if (map[0][j + 1] != 1 && map[0][j - 1] != 1) {
                    side += 5;
                }
            } else {
                side += 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("After the last column, fencing = " + side);}
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Map is valid
Corner fencing = 12.5
After the first row, fencing = 0.0
After the bottom row, fencing = 5.0
After the first column, fencing = 10.0
After the last column, fencing = 20.0
```

I've to point out that `first row fencing is equal to 0.0` not `5` and that's because of `(map[i + 1][0] != 1 && map[i - 1][0] != 1)` so you have to change this accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you want to calculate all the external faces of each element that is a 1 in your array and each face constitutes a fence with a weighting of 2.5m

Not that it's pretty, but this should basically do what you want:

```
public class Fencing {

public static void main(String[] args) {

  double totalFencingUnits = 0;
  double fencingUnitWeight = 2.5;

    boolean b = true;
    double corner = 0;
    double core = 0;
    double side = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int[][] map = { 
        { 0, 1, 1, 0 }, 
        { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, 
        { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, 
        { 1, 1, 0, 1 } 
    };


  for (i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < map[0].length; j++) {

            if (map[i][j] != 1 && map[i][j] != 0) {
                b = false;
                System.out.println("--> An invalid value of " + map[i][j] + " was found at " + i + "," + j);
            }

          if ( map[i][j] == 1){

            //do the outer corners
            if((i == 0 && (j == 0 || j == map.length - 1)) || (i == map.length - 1 && (j == 0 || j == map.length - 1))){
              System.out.println("A corner " + map[i][j] + " was found at " + i + "," + j);
              totalFencingUnits += 2;
              switch (2*i - j  ) {
                case -3:  
                  totalFencingUnits += map[i][j - 1] > 0?0:1;
                  totalFencingUnits += map[i + 1][j] > 0?0:1;
                 break;
                case 6:  
                 totalFencingUnits += map[i - 1][j] > 0?0:1;
                 totalFencingUnits += map[i ][j + 1] > 0?0:1;
                 break;
                case 0:  
                 totalFencingUnits += map[i][j + 1] > 0?0:1;
                 totalFencingUnits += map[i +1 ][j] > 0?0:1;
                 break;
                case 3:  
                 totalFencingUnits += map[i - 1][j] > 0?0:1;
                 totalFencingUnits += map[i ][j - 1] > 0?0:1;
                 break;
                default:
                break;
              }
            }
            //do the outer sides
            else if((i == 0 && (j != 0 && j != map.length - 1)) || (i == map.length - 1 && (j != 0 && j != map.length - 1))
              || (j == 0  && (i != 0 && i != map.length - 1)) || (j == map.length - 1 && (i != 0 && i != map.length - 1))){
              System.out.println("A side " + map[i][j] + " was found at " + i + "," + j);
              totalFencingUnits ++;
              if ( i == 0){
                totalFencingUnits += map[i][j - 1] > 0?0:1;
                 totalFencingUnits += map[i + 1][j] > 0?0:1;
                totalFencingUnits += map[i][j +  1] > 0?0:1;
              }
              if (i == map.length - 1){
                totalFencingUnits += map[i][j - 1] > 0?0:1;
                 totalFencingUnits += map[i -1 ][j] > 0?0:1;
                totalFencingUnits += map[i][j +  1] > 0?0:1;
              }
              if ( j == 0){
                totalFencingUnits += map[i - 1][j] > 0?0:1;
                 totalFencingUnits += map[i][j + 1] > 0?0:1;
                totalFencingUnits += map[i + 1][j ] > 0?0:1;
              }
              if ( j == map.length - 1){
                totalFencingUnits += map[i - 1][j] > 0?0:1;
                 totalFencingUnits += map[i][j - 1] > 0?0:1;
                totalFencingUnits += map[i + 1][j ] > 0?0:1;
              }

            }
            //now do the internals blocks
            else {

              System.out.println("An internal " + map[i][j] + " was found at " + i + "," + j);
              totalFencingUnits += map[i - 1][j] > 0?0:1;
                 totalFencingUnits += map[i][j - 1] > 0?0:1;
                totalFencingUnits += map[i ][j + 1] > 0?0:1;
              totalFencingUnits += map[i + 1][j ] > 0?0:1;

            }

          }
        }
    }

    if (b == false && i == 4) {
        System.out.println("The map is invalid");
        return;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Map is valid");
        System.out.println("TOTAL FENCING UNITS: " + totalFencingUnits );
        System.out.println("TOTAL FENCING WEIGHT: " + totalFencingUnits * fencingUnitWeight);
    }



    }
}
```

I ran this at [compilejava](https://www.compilejava.net/)

and got this output:

Map is valid
A side 1 was found at 0,1
A side 1 was found at 0,2
A side 1 was found at 1,0
An internal 1 was found at 1,1
An internal 1 was found at 1,2
A side 1 was found at 1,3
A side 1 was found at 2,0
An internal 1 was found at 2,1
An internal 1 was found at 2,2
A side 1 was found at 2,3
A corner 1 was found at 3,0
A side 1 was found at 3,1
A corner 1 was found at 3,3
TOTAL FENCING UNITS: 18.0
TOTAL FENCING WEIGHT: 45.0

Also, it looks like the output for the input I have is actually supposed to be 45 (ie. 18 faces).  Were you supposed to consider outside edges as well?